# Remove attributes like width inside a style element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to remove width inside of a style element, pref using the HTML Agility Pack.

I tried using:

```
public static void RemoveStyleAttributes(this HtmlDocument html)
{
   var elementsWithStyleAttribute = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@style");

   if (elementsWithStyleAttribute!=null)
   {
      foreach (var element in elementsWithStyleAttribute)
      {
         element.Attributes["style"].Remove();
      }
   }
}
```

but have been unable to target a single element inside of style (since I do not want to remove style entirely)

Comment: You can update the style attribute using `element.Attribute["style"].Value = YourStringmanipulationFunction(element.Attribute["style"].Value);` The function to manipulate the string, you'll have to build yourself or you'll need to grab from a library that can parse CSS. The AgilityPack does not contain such functions. This one may work for you: https://github.com/mckamey/jsonfx-v1#svn/trunk/JsonFx/JsonFx.BuildTools/CssCompactor

Comment: `width\s*\:.+?(?=\;)\s*?;` use that with RegEx.Replace(string,string), otherwise if it gets complicated find a library as suggested by jess